# I have a warning when creating a MySQL user

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu-18.04

I followed the following tutorial to create a MySQL database and a user :

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-drupal-on-ubuntu-18-04/

```
CREATE DATABASE drupal CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON drupal.* TO 'drupaluser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'change-with-strong-password';
```

The creation of the database works.

But I receive a warning when creating the user :

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the detail :

```
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                                                            |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1287 | Using GRANT for creating new user is deprecated and will be removed in future release. Create new user with CREATE USER statement. |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What should I enter as a command to add a user to my Drupal 8 database ?

Comment: Doesn't the warning tell you everything you need to know?

Comment: @BenM you have to create the user first and give him the database and permissions. How to do this ?

Comment: By first using `CREATE USER`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GRANT` to create a user on the fly is deprecated and will be removed in the future.

So instead, create a user then grant privileges to it.

Creating a user:

```
CREATE USER 'drupaluser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'change-with-strong-password';
```

Grant privileges:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON drupal.* TO 'drupaluser'@'localhost';
```

**Ps:** The 'dupal' database should be created before executing these commands.